# xserver boot failed after installing new GPU

Tags: boot, ati, graphics, xserver

I removed PCIe graphics card and changed to integrated AMD APU graphic card. After reboot woks only text regime. Xserver failed to boot. I tried:

`startx`

result was: ***starting load fallback graphics devices [FAIL]**

then i tried:

`/etc/init.d/gdm restart`

-no result

`aptitude reinstall lightdm`

-no result

Last thing i did was try to install Catalyst:

`./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-x86.x86_64.run`

it wrote something like "installation denied" (without reason)

i dont know how to repair it.

thanx for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-video-ati 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

and reboot.